# WebSocket replies to each client 'onConnect' with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server, client

I have a `ws.on('connection')` event on my server which sends a JSON object to each connected client on their first connection.

However because of this bit:

```
        // Sending the payload to all clients.
        wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
            // Prepare for transmission.
            let transmission = JSON.stringify(SocketObject.query());

            // Debug
            console.log('[server:onConnection:init]');

            // Send the transmission.
            client.send(transmission);
        });
```

Every time a client connects, the JSON object is transmitted to every client again and again. Is it possible to limit this reply to only the client that is getting connected initially?

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, so when wrapped like this:

```
    wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
        console.log('[server:onConnection]');
        ws.send('FIRST_RESPONSE');
```

... it does exactly what I need it to do. Meaning it only sends the message to the connected client. I don't know why I had the `forEach(client)` bit in there.